# IBM MQ Rest Api communication via mqweb

Tags: rest, ibm-mq, mq

Is it possible to configure multiple mqweb URLs on a single host? The host has multiple IP -s binded.
For example:

```
MQWB1124I: Server 'mqweb' is running. URLS:
https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/rest/v1/
https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console/
https://<random IP>:9444/ibmmq/rest/v1
https://<random2 IP>:9445/ibmmq/rest/v1
https://<random3 IP>:9446/ibmmq/rest/v1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `mqweb` to listen on all available network interfaces. Do this by configuring `httpHost` as an asterisk in double quotation marks.

For example:-

```
setmqweb properties -k httpHost -v "*"
```

Comment: Yeah but, if i want to specify 3 different IP adresses , then it is not working, only the last one that i configured.  Also if i use setmqweb properties -k httpHost -v "*" , then the wrong address showing up, even if its listen on the all IP -s of the host, i couldnt specify the ports, that i wanted. (in this case 9444, 9445 ,9446)

Comment: I couldn -t find other solution, so i used your solution, THX!

Comment: Indeed @Termite - you can't have 3 versions of the parameter. If you set it three times you are simply changing in. What do you mean by "the wrong address showing up". Can you show an example? You only have one (well two, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS) port parameter, so you can't have different IP addresses having different ports.